# Is there a difference between findOne and findByPk in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

Provided that you're looking for something based on its primary key and don't want to include any additional options, does it matter whether you use findOne or findByPk? Would the performance be the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Model.findByPk()` use `Model.findOne()` internally, you can see it from [v6.19.0/src/model.js#L1933](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.19.0/src/model.js#L1933). Both of these methods are a shortcut.

In the end, both methods call the more general `Model.findAll()` method, look [v6.19.0/src/model.js#L1968](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.19.0/src/model.js#L1968).

Both of them just do some parameter verification and create `where` clause options that have a negligible impact on performance.

The only difference is the usage.

`Model.findByPk(1)` is equivalent to `Model.findOne({primaryKey: 1})`, you need to specify the primary key by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, there is no difference between passing a pk to `findOne` or using `findByPk`, i.e the performance is the same.

It's just an abstraction that sequelize gives in order to get a much readable code.